# Options to update an app which is NOT on an app store?

Tags: ios, app-store

Situation:
I have an app, which is not listed in the apple app store.
Instead users download it from a link.

Is it possible to make the app update itself, when a new version is available?

I know this from some software, which checks for updates and if an update is available it asks the user to download and install it with a single click on a button. Is something like this is also possible with apps?

If not - is there any other way to make updates comfortable or do I have to use any app store?

Comment: How is the app signed?  Is it an enterprise signed app?  It should be possible to have the app check a website for version information and open an itms-services URL to install the new version

Comment: it is signed with the default signing of the apple developers program. is it only possible with the enterprise signing or can I use itms-service URL with the current signing also?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "default signing" - Is it an ad-hoc build that includes the UUIDs of the target devices?  I believe you can use an itms-service URL to install any build; whether it runs or not depends on whether there is a valid provisioning profile for the device it is installed on